# How to solve "rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound" in ros-indigo-ubuntu (14.04)?

Tags: python, ros, catkin

I am doing face detection robot using ros. I'm having trouble running the face detection node and am getting the error below:

```
arun@arun-Aspire-V5-121:~$ source /usr/share/setup.launch
arun@arun-Aspire-V5-121:~$ source ./ws1/devel/setup.bash
arun@arun-Aspire-V5-121:~$ rosrun exp2 face.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arun/ws1/src/exp2/scripts/face.py", line 4, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest('rosopencv')
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 208, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: rosopencv
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/arun/ws1/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Comment: `rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: rosopencv` fairly self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are missing **python** libraries in your system, you can download and install this first then you may be able to run your script.